# How to make an a tag function as a background to a div

Tags: html, css

I've been busting my head on what should be a simple problem. I've got a div that needs to be clickable, which means I have to put an `<a>` tag into the `<div>`. I can't put the entire content into an `<a>` tag, because there's text inside of this component which contains more inline `<a>` tags. (You can't have nested `<a>` tags, I've discovered).
So I thought it would be a simple solution to warp an `<a>` tag with a `<div>`, and just style the `<a>` tag so that it functions as a background to the `<div>`, with the other text containing the inline `<a>` tags showing *ontop* of the "clickable background". However I can't style it so that it functions as a background. My css knowledge is quite limited, I thought using `display: block` in combination with `padding: 100%` would solve this. That just messes up the entire layout, even when moving around the `<a>` tag in my html. Here's the relevant code:

CSS:

```
.clickable {
    background-color: $color-accent-white;
    display: block;
    padding: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<events>
    {{#each events}}
            <div>
                <section>
                    <div class="row">
                        <a class="clickable" href="{{ link }}" <!-- The culprit! -->
                           {{#if link_target}}target="{{ link_target }}"{{/if}} data-show-until="{{ show_until }}"></a>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                            {{> [content/content_picture]
                                large=image.large
                                alt=image.alt
                                link=null
                            }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                            <p class="mb-0">
                                <small>
                                    {{ subline }}
                                </small>
                            </p>
                            <p class="h3">
                                {{ headline }}
                            </p>
                            {{{ text }}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
    {{/each}}
</events>
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations with varying positions vs display modes and paddings. How can I make my `<a>` tag fit the size of it's parent `<div>`?

Comment: if you make your a tag fit the size of the parent, surely that's the same as wrapping the div anyway? I think the only way to do this would be to use js and put a click event on the main div to redirect to the main link and then click events on the child links to stop propagation so they will do their own clicks and stop the div click firing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the 2 guys who said to add a click listener to the div, that wouldn't work in my case because of styling, and needing the text inside of the div to also be clickable. To solve it, I first had to set the parent's position to relative, and the clickable `<a>` tag's position to absolute. I'll post the css below. The other part was setting the clickable element's z-index to the front, for it to still be clickable. And, in order for the inline links to still be clickable too, I had to set the z-index of these even higher, meaning I first had to select every `<a>` tag, set their z-index's to the front, then overwrite the clickable background to be one index lower. Code below:

CSS:

```
    a {
        z-index: 11;
        position: relative;
    }

    &-clickable {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<events>
    {{#each events}}
    <div>
        <section class="event mb-3 p-1">
            <a class="event-clickable" href="{{ link }}"
                     {{#if link_target}}target="{{ link_target }}"{{/if}} data-show-until="{{ show_until }}"></a>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                    {{> [content/content_picture]
                        large=image.large
                        alt=image.alt
                        link=null
                    }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                    <p class="mb-0">
                        <small>
                            {{ subline }}
                        </small>
                    </p>
                    <p class="h3">
                        {{ headline }}
                    </p>
                    {{{ text }}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</events>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the div an onclick attribute which triggers a javascript function to change the page.